# Propositional Logic: Confused on using operators with equal precedence

Tags: propositional-calculus

My problem involves using operators of equal precedence in propositional logic.

I'm trying to use truth tables to prove the following:

```
p ⇔ q ⇔ (p ⇒ q) ∧ (q ⇒ p)
```

My problem however stems from the fact that I can see 2 ways to go about this. One being:

```
(p ⇔ q) ⇔ ((p ⇒ q) ∧ (q ⇒ p))
```

and the other:

```
p ⇔ (q ⇔ (p ⇒ q) ∧ (q ⇒ p))
```

When writing out the truth tables for each, both of them result in a tautology, as can be seen here:

Truth table for **(p ⇔ q) ⇔ ((p ⇒ q) ∧ (q ⇒ p))**
[image]

Truth table for **p ⇔ (q ⇔ (p ⇒ q) ∧ (q ⇒ p))**
[image]

I'm certain that only one of those is correct. Would someone be able to explain which one and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second way is the right way according to reference [here](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/glossary/operator_precedence.html):

> When an operand is surrounded by operators of equal precedence, the operand associates to the right.

> p ⇒ q ⇒ r:     (p ⇒ (q ⇒ r))

> p ⇒ q ⇔ r:     (p ⇒ (q ⇔ r))