# Complex Natural Deduction proof

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

How do I provide a Natural Deduction proof for (¬A ∨ ¬B) → (C → A ∧ B)→ ¬C?

I know I can work backwards and i managed to get rid of the implications:

¬C

(C → A  ∧ B)→ ¬C

(¬A ∨ ¬B) → (C → A  ∧ B)→ ¬C

However i'm unsure where to go from here and what Hypotheses to choose, I've recently started Natural Deduction and I'm finding it pretty tricky

Comment: It's hard to give a good answer without knowing what system of natural deduction you are using. The idea will be to assume $\lnot A\lor \lnot B$ and $C\to A\land B$ and then prove $\lnot C.$ The presence of the disjunctive assumption $\lnot A\lor \lnot B$ suggests that you will need to do a case analysis, but how this is formalized precisely will depend on the details of the system you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In most logics connectives with same precedence are associated to the right by default (see a recent [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4285935/propositional-logic-confused-on-using-operators-with-equal-precedence/4286148#4286148)), so we need to prove $(¬A ∨ ¬B) → ((C → A ∧ B)→ ¬C)$. I'll sketch a proof below using the most common ND rules, and you should fill in your specific rules for your ND system:

Apparently we can try prove by cases:

```
 1 ¬A ∨ ¬B                        premise 
   2 ¬A                         
     3 C → A ∧ B                  assumption
       4 C                        assumption
       5 A ∧ B                    → E 3-4 (MP)
       6 A                        ∧ E
       7 ⊥                        ¬ E 2, 6
     8 (C → A ∧ B) → ¬C           ¬ I 4, 7

   9 ¬B                         
     10 C → A ∧ B                  assumption
       11 C                        assumption
       12 A ∧ B                    → E 10-11 
       13 B                        ∧ E
       14 ⊥                        ¬ E 9, 12
     15 (C → A ∧ B) → ¬C           ¬ I 11, 14

 16 (¬A ∨ ¬B) → ((C → A ∧ B)→ ¬C)  ∨ E
```

Finally please be aware that $((¬A ∨ ¬B) → (C → A ∧ B)) → ¬C$ is not valid which has an obvious counterexample when $A=B=C=True$.

Answer (score 0):

Those are indeed your targets.  So you need raise appropriate assumptions in subproofs aiming for them.  The skeleton should look *something* like this (in Fitch style), but will depend somewhat on the rules implemented in your proof system.

$$\def\fitch#1#2{~~~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{}{\fitch{\neg A\vee\neg B}{\fitch{C\to A\wedge B}{\fitch{C}{\vdots\\\bot}\\\neg C}\\(C\to(A\wedge B)\to\neg C}\\(\neg A\vee\neg B)\to((C\to(A\wedge B)\to\neg C)}$$

At the very least, you'll need a 'proof by cases' to eliminate that disjunction.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it,
$$\begin{align}
\neg A, C \to (A \wedge B), C &\vdash C &&\text{($\in$)}\\
\neg A, C \to (A \wedge B), C &\vdash C \to (A \wedge B) &&\text{($\in$)}\\
\neg A, C \to (A \wedge B), C &\vdash A \wedge B &&\text{($\to -$)}\\
\neg A, C \to (A \wedge B), C &\vdash A &&\text{($\wedge -$)}\\
\neg A, C \to (A \wedge B), C &\vdash \neg A &&\text{($\in$)}\\
\neg A, C \to (A \wedge B) &\vdash \neg C &&\text{($\neg +$), (4), (5)}\\
\neg A &\vdash (C \to (A \wedge B)) \to \neg C &&\text{($\to +$)}\\
\neg B, C \to (A \wedge B), C &\vdash C &&\text{($\in$)}\\
\neg B, C \to (A \wedge B), C &\vdash C \to (A \wedge B) &&\text{($\in$)}\\
\neg B, C \to (A \wedge B), C &\vdash A \wedge B &&\text{($\to -$)}\\
\neg B, C \to (A \wedge B), C &\vdash B &&\text{($\wedge -$)}\\
\neg B, C \to (A \wedge B), C &\vdash \neg B &&\text{($\in$)}\\
\neg B, C \to (A \wedge B) &\vdash \neg C &&\text{($\neg +$), (11), (12)}\\
\neg B &\vdash (C \to (A \wedge B)) \to \neg C &&\text{($\to +$)}\\
\neg A \vee \neg B &\vdash (C \to (A \wedge B)) \to \neg C &&\text{($\vee -$), (7), (14)}\\
\emptyset &\vdash (\neg A \vee \neg B) \to ((C \to (A \wedge B)) \to \neg C) &&\text{($\to +$)}
\end{align}$$